# How to use URL in Kotlin/Native

Tags: url, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

**I want to load some stuff from internet in my common Kotlin/Native module.**

I've searched for some examples [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples) and i haven't found any URL related. 
I know that Kotlin/Native supports only several libraries like `ktor, kotlinx.io, kotlinx.serialization` and other.

So is there a way to download anything from internet like image using given multiplatform libraries, maybe i've missed sth?

Comment: ktor includes a multiplatform HTTP client. On which platforms is your code running?

Comment: @yole android and ios. Ok then how to download some web page using ktor?

Comment: https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/calls/requests.html

Comment: @OmarMainegra exactly! Thanks